# PHP file_get_contents ignoring timeout?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, connection-timeout

```
$url = 'http://a.url/i-know-is-down';

//ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5);

$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 5,
        'ignore_errors' => true
        )
    )
);

$start = microtime(true);
$content = @file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start, "\n";
```

the response I get is generally 21.232 segs, shouldn't be about five seconds???

Uncommenting the ini_set line don't help at all.

Comment: Could you try turning off both the "ignore_errors" flag as well as the silent @file_get_contents() call and see if any obvious errors pop out?

Comment: @Mahdi.M: I can not turn off `ingnore_errors` because I need to distinguish between say a 404 error and an error generated by connectivity problems. Let me rephrase it. If ingnore_errors` is off and the server return a 404 $content would be false and i need to know if $content if false because a 404 error or beacuse a connectivity error. The error showed when I suppress the @ operator is a generic one like `file_get_contents(filename): failed to open stream`

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't ever need to use @. If it's critical to your application, you are likely writing it in the wrong way. Not always, but pretty damn often!

Comment: @Cesar: if you need to distinguish HTTP Error codes, read `$http_response_header` after calling `file_get_contents()`. It gets populated as an array of the HTTP Headers returned by the server. You can get all errors except server connection problems (server not found, timeout, connection refused, etc)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are setting the *read* timeout with `socket_create_context`. If the *page* you are trying to access doesn't exist then the server will let you connect and give you a 404. However, if the *site* doesn't exist (won't resolve or no web server behind it), then `file_get_contents()` will ignore read timeout because it hasn't even timed out connecting to it yet.

I don't think you can set the connection timeout in `file_get_contents`. I recently rewrote some code to use `fsockopen()` exactly because it lets you specify [connect timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)

```
$connTimeout = 30 ;
$fp = fsockopen($hostname, $port, $errno, $errstr, $connTimeout);
```

Ofcourse going to fsockopen will require you to then `fread()` from it in a loop, compicating your code slightly. It does give you more control, however, on detecting read timeouts while reading from it using `stream_get_meta_data()`

http://php.net/stream_get_meta_data