# file_get_contents timeout

Tags: php, timeout, file-get-contents

I am using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), and I want to [define a timeout](http://php.net/manual/context.http.php). I tried to do it by creating a context like this:

```
$timeout = array('http' => array('timeout' => 6));

$context = stream_context_create($timeout);

$xml = file_get_contents($hostName,false,$context);
```

But It ignores this value.

Comment: How can you say that it ignores that timeout setting?

Comment: `timeout` was added in 5.2.1, check your PHP version.

Comment: I assigned a small value to the timeout and in spite of this file_get_contents returns the good result

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the default time out set is 60 sec. 
You can change that to what ever value you want to.

```
<?php

$ctx=stream_context_create(array('http'=>
    array(
        'timeout' => 30 // 30 sec
    )
));

$conetnt = file_get_contents('http://example.com',false,$ctx);
var_dump($conetnt);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.2.1 you can specify `timeout` context option and pass the context to file_get_contents()

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout',    120);
```

Comment: I alreadey tried this

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5);   
$xml = file_get_contents($hostName);

But It doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Since I still cannot comment (and editing or flagging the question (as a duplicate(?)) probably is not quite appropriate in this case), let me add a follow-up question, and a comment as an answer:

- When you said:

  > I assigned a small value to the timeout and in spite of this file_get_contents returns the good result

Do you mean that even if you set a time-out of, say, 1 second, file_get_contents() takes more that that, and doesn't time out? Do you have any low level monitoring available to distinguish the time it takes to "connect", and "read" data?

- Because as Fanis said in his answer to question "[PHP file_get_contents ignoring timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689371/php-file-get-contents-ignoring-timeout)", if you're using "file_get_contents()" (and not lower level socket functions), the time to "*connect*" to the remote server cannot be set by the available ini setting, or the context entry apparently. You only set the "*read*" time out by those.

(I realize this is an old question but, I ran into these 2 in my searches as I had the same question, and thought I should set up the link between them)