# file get content or fsockopen - timeout issue

Tags: php, file-get-contents, fsockopen, connection-timeout

I have a php file called testResponse.php which is only :

```
<?php
 sleep(5);
 echo"go";
?>
```

Now, I'm calling this file from a another page using file_get_contents like this :

```
$start= microtime(true);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 1
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$loc = @file_get_contents("http://www.mywebsite.com/testResponse.php", false, $context);
$end= microtime(true);
echo $end - $start, "\n";
```

The output is more than 5 sec, which means that my timeout has been ignored...
I followed the advice of this post : [stackoverflow.com/questions/3689371](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689371/php-file-get-contents-ignoring-timeout)

But it seems that hostname cannot be a path (like www.mywebsite.com/testResponse.php) but directly the hostname like www.mywebsite.com.

So I'm stuck to achieve this goal :

Get content of page www.test.com/x.php with constraint :

- if test.com doesn't exist or the page x.php doesn't exist returns nothing quickly
- if the page exist but takes more than 1 sec to load, abort
- else get the content of the file

**Edit :** By the way, it seems to work when I call this page (testResponse.php) from my local server. Well, it multiply the timeout by 2. For instance, If I have 1 for timeout, I will have echoed something like "2.0054645". But only from local...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use PHP's [**cURL functions.**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) The other question you linked to explains things properly, about the *read timeouts* vs. the *connection timeouts*, and so on, but neither of those are truly what you're looking for here.  Even the *connection timeout* won't work, because the connection to `testResponse.php` is always successful; after that it's *waiting*, so what you need is an **execution timeout.** This is where cURL comes in handy.

So, `testResponse.php` doesn't need to be altered. In your main file, though, try the following code (this is tested and it works on my server):

```
$start = microtime(true);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite.com/testResponse.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
if ($errno > 0) {
    if ($errno === 28) {
        echo "Connection timed out.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error #" . $errno . ": " . curl_error($ch);
    }
}
else {
    echo $output;
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo "<br><br>" . ($end - $start);
curl_close($ch);
```

This sets the **execution time** of the cURL session, via the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` option you see on line 5. So, when the connection is timed out, `$errno` will equal `28`, the code for cURL's operation timeout error. The rest of the error codes are [listed in the cURL documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), so you can expand the script above to act accordingly.

Finally, because of the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option that's set, `curl_exec($ch)` will be set to the content of the retrieved page if the session succeeds. Otherwise, it will equal `false`.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** Removed the statement setting `CURLOPT_HEADER`. I also, for some reason, was under the impression that `curl_exec($ch)` set the value of `$ch` to the returned contents, forgetting that the contents are returned by `curl_exec()`.

Comment: It seems it is almost good. To use a timeout less than 1 sec, I used `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 3000);`. Is it OK? And also, how do I get the content of the page ? In my case it's an XML.
`echo $ch;` is returning : "Resource id #8"

Comment: `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` should be fine, but depending on your version of PHP, that constant [**might not actually be set properly**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#107314), and you might have to use the integer `155` instead of the constant. As for the XML, once you've retrieved `$ch`, you can create a new XML element like so: `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($ch);` See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561816/php-curl-extract-an-xml-response) for more details.

Comment: Ok I found it. I had to remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);` and also the content is returned by `curl_exec($ch);`. THanks mate