# Set a timeout for both connect and read in file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

### Prerequisites

**Cluster server**

I have a server that runs a number of virtual "cluster nodes". Basically, each one of them is a public, very minimal HTTP server, that has two functions:

```
127.0.0.1:XXXXn/ping
127.0.0.1:XXXXn/api/arg/arg/arg
```

Both of those functions return a 200OK header followed by HTML. `ping` is used to test if the node is busy or not. If node `n` is busy, the connection will just time out (because the node is busy handling another request). However, if the node is responsive and available, `ping` will return

```
PING=NODE.FREE
```

**Calling server**

I want to write a PHP program that can be loaded on any webserver to expose a better interface for the API. The following code is from an older API version that only had one node per IP, thus the code was quite simple:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    echo file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:XXXX9/".$_REQUEST['script']."/".$_REQUEST['query']."/".$_REQUEST['sort']."/".$_REQUEST['num']);
?>
```

This was, of course, called like

```
http://server.org/api.php?script=api&query=... (etc.)
```

and would return results from node #9 (hence `XXXX9`). There are 10 nodes populating one server, so 10 servers from `:XXXX0` to `:XXXX9`.

### The Goal

I want to implement PHP (i.e. webserver-side-) load balancing. Basically, when called, the PHP program should loop through all nodes until one node does successfully return `PING=NODE.FREE` in less than a specified amount of time.

Since I use `file_get_contents`, I read up on ways to set a timeout for this. As it turns out, there are quite a few ways, for example using the stream context, or a curl option (instead of file_...). The problem I think I am facing is that each of the options (presented in these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236166/does-file-get-contents-have-a-timeout-setting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689371/php-file-get-contents-ignoring-timeout/3690321#3690321)) is only affecting either the connection *or* the read.

What I want to check for is, if in the given time (say 1000ms per node), the node connects *and* returns the message. Then, and *only* then, the code should proceed to call the API at this node using the above syntax. Of course, if there is no node avail. atm., it should loop until one is free.

Now, what is the best and safest way to set and check for this timeout? If possible, I'd like to avoid `fsock`, because this is disabled for most managed webservers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, using the stream context method:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

$streamContext = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 1, // timeout in seconds (varies +- 1 sec or so)
    )
));

$iFreeNode = -1;

while (true) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {

        $bNodeAvailable = @file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:XXXX'.$i.'/ping', false, $streamContext);

        if ($bNodeAvailable === false) {
            //echo "Node ".$i." busy.<br>";
        } else {
            if ($bNodeAvailable = "PING=NODE.FREE") {
                //echo "Node ".$i." available.<br>";
                $iFreeNode = $i;
                break;
            } else {
                //echo "Node ".$i." busy.<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    if ($iFreeNode > -1) { break; }
}
echo file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:XXXX".$iFreeNode."/".$_REQUEST['script']."/".$_REQUEST['query']."/".$_REQUEST['sort']."/".$_REQUEST['num']);
?>
```